# Hyperbolic 3-manifolds with no geometrically finite structure

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology

Does there exist a compact hyperbolic 3-manifold $M$ that is not diffeomorphic to a geometrically finite hyperbolic manifold? If yes, can such $M$ have incompressible boundary?

I think the answer should be yes to both questions but I cannot find this in the literature.

**Remarks:** as usual, a *compact hyperbolic manifold* is a compact manifold whose interior carries a complete hyperbolic structure. The structure is
 *geometrically finite* if it is obtained as the quotient of the hyperbolic 3-space by a geometrically finite group. Thurston's hyperbolization theorem implies:

1. A compact 3-manifold with non-empty boundary is hyperbolizable if and only if it is irreducible and atoroidal.
2. Any compact, atoroidal, pared 3-manifold is diffeomorphic to a geometrically finite one.
3. Any compact hyperbolic 3-manifold is homotopy equivalent to a geometrically finite one.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question negatively, essentially from 1. and 2.  You can see this stated in a survey paper of Dick Canary: 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1316167

Comment: Igor, it is also in my book, where I include a proof for orbifolds as well. 

Comment: Ian and Misha, are you saying that every irreducible, atoroidal 3-manifold with non-empty boundary is pared? Canary's survey is not in our library. Where is this statement in Misha's book? Thanks!

Comment: To show that every irreducible, atoroidal 3-manifold with non-empty boundary has a structure of a pared manifold one has to include toroidal boundary in the parabolic locus, and then I do not know how to rule out essential cylinders that might a priori join different toroidal components. 

Comment: @Igor - Yes.  The paring locus can be empty!

Comment: If the manifold has tori in the boundary, and has an essential cylinder connecting torus boundary components (or connecting a torus boundary component to itself) then the manifold is algebraically toroidal (and thus geometrically toroidal or small Seifert fibered).

Comment: I do not know enough 3d topology, which is why I do not see why an essential cylinder connecting torus boundary components forces the manifold to be toroidal or Seifered fibered. It seems reasonable in case $M$ is geometrically finite, but this is not our assumption.

Comment: My last comment doesn't use anything from the theory of Kleinian groups. It is instead part of the JSJ theory. 

Comment: @Igor: let an annulus A connect two tori T and T'. Now take a regular neighborhood N of A \cup T \cup T': this is a 3-manifold with boundary (contained in your bigger manifold M), and its boundary is necessarily made of three tori T, T', and a new one T''. This new torus T'' is contained in M: either it is incompressible (and hence M is toroidal, against your hypothesis) or is compressible. In the latter case it bounds a solid torus S: hence you get M = N \cup S which is a Seifert manifold.

Comment: (@Bruno - One last case: the new torus is parallel into the boundary.)

Comment: Thank you, Bruno! Finally, we are getting to the issue I am confused about. What criterion do you use to recognize that $M$ is Seifert?
Also I assume that if twe new torus is boundary parallel, $M$ must be
$T^2\times I$, correct?

Comment: Ok, I now understand what the confusion is. In fact, if one has a compact manifold with hyperbolic interior, then there can be no essential annulus connecting the rank 2 cusps (if there are rank one cusps, one can ignore them). Therefore, your observation 1. implies the pared structure is acylindrical, and thus by 2. there is a geometrically finite structure. 

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to say pared acylindrical, just pared, i.e. there are no essential annuli with boundary on the toroidal boundary components. 

Comment: The regular neighborhood N is homeromophic to the product PxS^1 of a pair-of-pants P and the circle S^1. If the new boundary torus is parallel, then M is homeomorphic to N and hence to PxS^1, which is Seifert fibred. Otherwise, the new torus bounds a solid torus: then M = PxS^1 plus a solid torus. Such an object is either a Seifert manifold (fibering over the annulus with at most one singular fiber) or a connected sum of two solid tori (this very special case happens when the meridian of the solid torus is attached to the fiber of PxS^1).

Comment: Thanks, Bruno and Ian. Reference to Hatcher's notes found by Sam resolved my confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edited several times] As the comments say, the answer to the first and hence to the second question is "no". Suppose that $M$ is the compact manifold and $N$ is its interior.  Let $\rho$ be the given hyperbolic structure on $N$.  If $M$ is without boundary then the volume of $\rho$ is finite and we are done.

Suppose instead that $M$ has boundary.  Since $N$ is hyperbolic, via $\rho$, deduce $M$ is atoroidal (which includes aspherical).  Thus $M$ is Haken.  Place all tori in the boundary of $M$ into the paring locus $P$.  By Thurston's hyperbolization theorem, the interior $N$ admits a hyperbolic metric, $\rho_0$, which is geometrically finite.  (The convex core has finite volume and contains all torus boundary components.) See Theorem 1.43 in Kapovich's book.

[A brief note - your hypotheses can be weakened.  You assumed (a) $N$ is the interior of a compact manifold and (b) N is hyperbolizable.  This can be replaced by (a') $\pi_1(N)$ is finitely generated and the same (b).  This is called the "tameness theorem", due to Agol and also Calegari-Gabai.]

In the comments below (above?) Igor asks why an atoroidal manifold with torus boundary, and admitting an essential annulus, is Seifert fibered.  This can be found as Lemma 1.16 on page 25 of Hatcher's three-manifold [notes](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mfds.pdf).

Comment: Sam, this is not an answer because it misses the most interesting case when $M$ has a boundary component of genus $>1$. In this case $N$ does not admit a finite volume hyperbolic metric. Of course, it might still admit a complete infinite volume hyperbolic metric.

Comment: You are correct - I was referring to the wrong thing.  I have added a temporary fix, and will look for a precise reference. 

Comment: If what you say is true, why would anyone bother to prove the weaker statement 3 in my list (which is theorem 19.6 in Misha's book)?

Comment: Because Theorem 19.6 is a different path to proving the hyperbolization theorem. See the remarks immediately after the proof of Theorem 15.3, at the top of page 372.

Comment: Sam, I would appreciate, if you could include in your answer a detailed explaination why a hyperbolizable manifold can contain no essential annulus joining two torus boundaries. This is the only thing I did not (and still do not) understand; what you wrote does not tell me anything new except stating that the answer is "no".

Comment: @Igor - I suggest you ask this (new, to my eyes) question in a separate post. However, very briefly, a hyperbolic manifold is algebraically atoroidal - that is, any $Z^2$ subgroup is parabolic. [This is an exercise in hyperbolic geometry, using the discreteness of the group.] Let's now do just one of the many cases. Suppose that $S$ and $T$ are boundary tori, and $A$ is an annulus between them. Let $K$ be a small neighborhood of $S \cup A \cup T$. Then $K$ is homeomorphic to $P \times I$ where $P$ is a pair of pants. So $\pi_1(K)$ is a rank two free group, crossed with $Z$.

Comment: There are lots of copies of $Z^2$ in $\pi_1(K)$ and all of them have to be parabolic.  This leads to contradictions.  

Comment: There is a purely geometric proof, as well.  Suppose $N$ is hyperbolic, and $B_S$ and $B_T$ are disjoint horo-tori about $S$ and $T$. Suppose that $A$ is a compact annulus connecting $B_S$ to $B_T$.  Lift everything to the universal cover.  A component of the lift of $A$ is a strip (quasi-isometric to a line!) that fellow-travels lines in two distinct horospheres, a contradiction. 

Comment: It is not a new question because after checking that an atoroidal, irreducible manifold is pared, you are done by Thurston (e.g. Theorem 1.43 of Misha's book which was initially stated in my question). Checking that it is pared is the only thing that takes some work. Anyway, thank you for the input. I will try filling in the details.


Comment: I will add a reference to my answer. 


Comment: So that I do not forget: the boundary tori of an irreducible, atoroidal compact 3-manifold must be incompressible because in the geometrically finite structure they correspond to rank two cusps,
which are incompressible.

Comment: @Igor - Not quite!  For example, the solid torus $S^1 \times B^2$ is irreducible and atoroidal (and hyperbolizable!) but the boundary torus is compressible.  There are also Seifert fibered spaces which satisfy the hypothesis and conclusion, but that are of course not hyperbolic.  

Comment: [See page 14, paragraph (3) of Hatcher's notes.] Basically, if a boundary torus $T$ compresses, then there is a disk $D$ with various properties.  Take a neighborhood $K$ of $T \cup D$ and consider the frontier of $K$ in the manifold $M$.  This will be a sphere and so bound a ball in $M$, by irreducibility.  Thus $M$ is a solid torus.  